# UITableView second prototype cell does not appear to be respecting custom height?

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, storyboard, uikit

I am dequeuing the second prototype cell but the height of the cell appears to not be respected.

[image]

Can anyone lead me in the right direction ? I have tried searching google with no avail.

---

The problem has been solved,my solution is implementing in code:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CGFloat height;
    if ([indexPath row] == 0) {
        height = 170.0f;
    }
    else  {
        height = 72.0f;
    }
    return height;
}
```

[image: Fixed!]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to implemented the table view delegate method `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` in order to change a cell's height. you can't do this purely in storyboards.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I had no clue that storyboards did not respect that aspect

Comment: no problem :) just don't forget to tick the green checkmark :)

Answer (score 0):

Remember

> storyboards or xib can not dequeue cell  without code,so you have to setDelegate and write in code `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath` ,

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CGFloat height;
    if ([indexPath row] == 0) {
        height = 100.f;
    }
    else  {
        height = 50.f;
    }
    return height;
}
```